# Why i am getting segmentation fault when changing const static variable through non-constant pointer variable?

Tags: c, static, constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // case 1
    const int a = 10;
    int * ptr1 = &a;
    *ptr1 = 11;
    printf("%d\n",*ptr1);
    
    // case 2
    const static int b = 10;
    static int * ptr2 = &b;
    *ptr2 = 11;
    printf("%d\n",*ptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

In this program I can understand the case 1 (By assigning the address of the const variable to a non-constant pointer, We can change the variable value). if I apply the same concept to case 2 i won't work. It gives segmentation fault. What is the reason ? Is there is any other concept for case2 ? Here I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: A decent compiler should give you a warning for the pointer variable initializations. And if you don't get one, then enable more warnings. And treat warnings as errors.

Comment: "*By assigning the address of the const variable to a non-constant pointer, We can change the variable value*" -- perhaps.  Or perhaps you just prevent the compiler from diagnosing the problem.

Comment: As stated in the answer below, both cases are UB. Technically, on your particular architecture with particular compiler and flags, `a` has automatic storage class and located on stack. Stack has read-write permissions. `b` has static storage class and likely located at read-only section because of `const`. Write access to read-only region causes segmentation fault.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: As said by others: Treat all warnings as errors, use at least '-Wall -Werror -Wextra' flags when testing. If you want to learn why, compile with '-fsanitize=address' flag only. You'll get two warnings at compilation, and ASan will print the error at execution.

Comment: @Fredrik: [The code does compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/nh813KdKb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By attempting to modify a `const` object through a non-const pointer, that triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your program.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.3p6 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
> of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

When you have undefined behavior in your program, there is no guarantee of what it will do.  It might crash (as in your second case), it might give strange results, or it may appear to work properly (as in your first case).

So both cases have undefined behavior.  They just happen to manifest differently.

Answer (score 4):

In case 1, `a` has automatic storage duration. Automatic storage duration is most often implemented using the hardware stack, except when optimization keeps a value in a register or folds it into expressions. The stack cannot be read-only because it is used for many non-const things, so the C implementation is unable to enforce const for `a`.

In case 2, `b` has static storage duration, and it is put into an area of memory with other `const` objects. That memory is marked read-only (after it is initialized), which enforces the const property.

This behavior is specific to your C implementation and particular circumstances and may vary when circumstances change. It is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: `"the C implementation is unable to enforce const for a"` Here this line make me confusing. Until now I thinking `In stack a separate read-only memory allocate for a`. Because when I try to change value a `a=22;` it gives compiler error `error: assignment of read-only variable 'a'` . Please can you explain more here.

Comment: @Baranitharan: In `a=22;`, the compiler can see from the type of `a` that it is const-qualified and should not be assigned to, so it issues a diagnostic message for that. In `*ptr1 = 11;`, the compiler cannot see from the type of `ptr` or `*ptr` that it is const-qualified. (In simple code, the compiler could deduce this by analyzing code flow, but this cannot be done in general.) So the compiler does not issue a diagnostic message while compiling. For the static object, hardware memory protection enforces the read-only property. For the automatic object, it does not.